# Selecting a dropdownlist by tabbing into it, which event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, keyboard, css-selectors

I have a javascript function that needs to run when a user clicks on a dropdownlist, basically it needs to show some extra information about the option in that dropdownlist.

```
$('.scaleAnswersDropDown').click(function () { ShowExtraInfo(); });
```

This works as intended, but doesn't trigger when the user uses the tab key to select the dropdownlist... Is there a way to capture this event and as such show the extra info as well?

thanks

Sam

Comment: Nice thanks! You should make this a real answer, so I can accept it though.

Comment: You can vote up comments, and it's not much of an answer, just a pointer to an answer, which I didn't write. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

api.jquery.com/focus – Meke 36 mins ago

Copied for closure. :)